# How to use a builder function on a StatefulWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a flutter app. I am trying to use a builder function for a hero tag like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Page());

class Page extends StatefulWidget {

  final String open;

  Page({this.open});

  @override
  PageState createState() => PageState();

}

class PageState extends State<Page> {

  String open;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp (
      home: Scaffold (
        body: Hero (
          tag: open,
          child: Material ()
        )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

But this code gives me an error Saying

```
Failed assertion: line 128 pos 15: 'tag != null': is not true
```

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass string as `Page()` is expecting one, so it can assign it to `hero` tag.

Plus in state you can access that string with `widget.` method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Page(
      open: 'open',  // Add this
    ));

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final String open;

  Page({this.open});

  @override
  PageState createState() => PageState();
}

class PageState extends State<Page> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Hero(tag: widget.open, child: Material())));
  }
}
```